# Code not working in Chrome extension as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a Chrome extension, which could check drop down option from my multi-select drop-down checkbox list.
I have various different option given in Chrome extension UI i.e. randomly checking, index based checking, no. of checkbox to check.

**What I tried**

```
function SelectRandomCheckBoxFromList(checkBoxListNameCheckBox, checkboxCheckRandom, checkboxCheckUpto, checkboxCheckFixed, checkboxCheckOnIndex) {
    if (checkboxCheckOnIndex) {
        for (var indexBoundCheck = 0; indexBoundCheck < checkboxCheckOnIndex.length; indexBoundCheck++) {
            if (checkboxCheckOnIndex[indexBoundCheck] > checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $(checkBoxListNameCheckBox[checkboxCheckOnIndex[indexBoundCheck]]).prop('checked', true).change();
            }
        }
    } else if (checkboxCheckRandom) {
        var randomSelectionLength = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length - 1);
        for (var indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox = 0; indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox < randomSelectionLength; indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox++) {
            var randomSelection = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length - 1);
            $(checkBoxListNameCheckBox[randomSelection]).prop('checked', true).change();
        }
    } else if (checkboxCheckUpto) {
        if (checkboxCheckUpto > checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length) {
            checkboxCheckUpto = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length - 1);
        }
        var randomSelectionLength = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkboxCheckUpto - 1);
        for (var indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox = 0; indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox < randomSelectionLength; indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox++) {
            var randomSelection = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length - 1);
            $(checkBoxListNameCheckBox[indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox]).prop('checked', true).change();
        }

    } else if (checkboxCheckFixed) {
        if (checkboxCheckFixed > checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length) {
            checkboxCheckFixed = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length - 1);
        }
        for (var indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox = 0; indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox < checkboxCheckFixed; indexOfCheckBoxListNameCheckBox++) {
            var randomSelection = GetRandomNumberFromRange(0, checkBoxListNameCheckBox.length - 1);
            $(checkBoxListNameCheckBox[randomSelection]).prop('checked', true).change();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine for normal checkbox, but could not check checkbox in multi-select dropdownlist.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: This question does not appear to have anything to do with the specific issues of being in a Chrome extension environment. It is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should try using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for your code to show a [mcve] which duplicates the problem. At a minimum, you need to include the HTML against which you expect this code to run.